# Can't import module "Selenium"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have successfully installed selenium with `pip install selenium`.

I work on pycharm, running just python and I'm using windows.

After doing `import selenium`, I was expecting it would successfully import selenium.

Instead, I get this result:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`

Comment: Try installing using `python -m pip install selenium`. `pip` may be leftover from an old python install, so make sure you're installing to your version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing `pip install selenium` you are installing `selenium` to you global Python installation. But a project created with Pycharm will by default use its own virtual environment.

You need to install `selenium` to the `virtualenv` your project is using.
That can be easily done from Pycharm:

```
> File (from menu bar)
> Settings
> Project: projectname
> Project interpreter
> click + and search for package
> Install packge
```

More detailed instructions with images: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: While a link to instructions is useful now, that link may go dead in the future. Please summarize the basic steps in your answer (keeping the link is fine, but in addition to the steps).

Comment: @JeffC Good idea :) did just that!